# How can I represent the function chain using compose?

Tags: node.js, function-composition, highland.js

I am using the `highlandjs` library to read files and add an end card to their contents before displaying them in the console:

```
const readFile = highland.wrapCallback(fs.readFile);
const addEndCard = x => x + '\nx---THE END---x\n';
files.map(readFile).parallel(3).map(addEndCard).each(console.log);
```

I would like to use `highland.compose` to wrap these into a single function call, I started with:

```
const readAllFiles = highland.compose(
  highland.map,
  addEndCard,
  readFile
);
readAllFiles(files).parallel(3).each(console.log);
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: readAllFiles(...).parallel is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vamsi/Do/highland-fun/index.js:14:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:980:3
```

It looks like the composed function is not returning a `highland stream`.

Answer (score 0):

`readFile` returns a stream but [_.compose()](http://highlandjs.org/#compose) composes functions not streams.

I believe what you're looking for is [_.pipeline()](http://highlandjs.org/#pipeline).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your composed function is not returning a stream is that by passing `map` as you have done there you are using a curried function that is expecting two arguments. `compose` works by passing the result of applying each function in series from right to left, i.e, each function in the composition must be unary; when `map` receives a single argument it returns a function expecting the final argument rather than a result and it breaks the rest of the functions downstream. Something like this should work:

```
highland(files) // I presume files is an array
  .map(highland.compose(highland.map(addEndCard), readFile))
  .parallel(3)
  .each(console.log);
```

Also, the only way I could maintain your original API was like this:

```
const readAllFiles = highland.compose(
  highland.map(highland.map(addEndCard)),
  files => files.map(file => readFile(file))
);

readAllFiles(files).parallel(3).each(console.log);
```

Btw, are you using `parallel` over `merge` for a reason? If the order the files are processed in doesn't matter, use `merge`.